# Why won't window minimize or maximize?

Tags: windows, go

I have been having several issues trying to set an active window (Ex: Calculator.exe) and minimizing and maximizing it. I have found several resources on here and none of them seem to be actually minimizing the window or restoring it.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
func main() {
    fpid, err := robotgo.FindIds("Calculator")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(len(fpid))
    if len(fpid) > 0 {
        fmt.Println("pid----", fpid[0])
        robotgo.ActivePID(fpid[0])

        tl := robotgo.GetTitle(fpid[0])
        fmt.Println("pid[0] title is: ", tl)

        x, y, w, h := robotgo.GetBounds(fpid[0])
        fmt.Println("GetBounds is: ", x, y, w, h)

        robotgo.MinWindow(fpid[0])
        // robotgo.MaxWindow(fpid[0])
        // robotgo.CloseWindow(fpid[0])
    }
}
```

The output is here below:

```
$ go run main.go
1
pid---- 10604
pid[0] title is:  MSCTFIME UI
GetBounds is:  0 0 0 0
```

So I am getting the correct PID but it seems the remaining functions are not working as intended.

Comment: `MSCTFIME` is Windows' IME, not its calculator. I don't know why you think it's working...

Comment: @Dai I never said I thought it was working. I said that I am getting the correct PID for the calc process but nothing else seems to be correct.

Comment: Have you used your step-through debugger?